# Trouble with Custom Command in Custom Plugin. How do I do it?

Tags: plugin-development

I found the documentation here very confusing: https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/commands.html#module-setup

I've scaffolded a simple test plugin from https://pluginfactory.io/ with "Console Commands" enabled and I've pulled my plugin into composer via 'path'. The plugin shows up fine in the Craft UI, and so I installed it.

However, I can't get the new command to display in the terminal when I do a 'php craft'. Am I supposed to see it?

Comment: Maybe there is something missing. I would also suggest you to take a look on some popular plugins and how they implemented custom commands.

Answer (score 1):

You should see your commands when using the Craft CLI.

First thing to check would be that the module is registered in `app.php`, both in the `modules` and `bootstrap` arrays. Craft's documentation on that is [here](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/module-guide.html#update-the-application-config).

I find the best way to quickly validate that your module is registered, is by dumping something out from the module `init()` function. `Craft::dd('Registered')` does the trick. If you don't see anything on the frontend, your module isn't getting loaded into Craft.

Secondly, I would check that you are correctly setting the `controllerNamespace`, so that Craft knows where to look for controllers, depending on your request. Their documentation on that is [here](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/commands.html#module-setup).

Finally, check that you have some valid functions setup in your controllers. Each function name should be prefixed with `action`. For example: `actionRun()` in a `JobController.php` file will be run with `php craft mymodule/job/run`.